# Regex to count the number of capturing groups in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that examines arbitrary regex (as a string), returning the number of capturing groups. So far I have...

```
arbitrary_regex.toString().match(/\((|[^?].*?)\)/g).length
```

Which works for some cases, where the assumption that any group that starts with a question mark, is non-capturing. It also counts empty groups.

It does not work for brackets included in character classes, or escaped brackets, and possibly some other scenarios.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Modify your regex so that it will match an empty string, then match an empty string and see how many groups it returns:

```
var num_groups = (new RegExp(regex.toString() + '|')).exec('').length - 1;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EEn6G/

Comment: Can someone explain what the pipe stands for?

Comment: The pipe is for alternation, so the regex `a|b` would match either "a" or "b".  For this answer it is more like `a|`, which will match either "a" or an empty string ("").

Comment: Why `regex.toString()`? That contains the slashes, which are unnecessary to include in the new regex. I think `regex.source` would be a  bit better.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is what you should use in any production system. However, if you wanted to solve it using a regex for fun, you can do that as shown below. It assumes the regex you want the number of groups in is correct.

Note that the number of groups is just the number of non-literal `(`s in the regex. The strategy we're going to take is instead of matching all the correct `(`, we're going to **split** on all the incorrect stuff in between them.

```
re.toString().split(/(\(\?|\\\[|\[(?:\\\]|.)*?\]|\\\(|[^(])+/g).length - 1
```

You can see how it works on [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28%5C%28%5C%3F%7C%5C%5C%5C%5B%7C%5C%5B%28%3F%3A%5C%5C%5C%5D%7C.%29%2A%3F%5C%5D%7C%5C%5C%5C%28%7C%5B%5E%28%5D%29%2B&flags=&str=%28asdf%28asdf%28%5Bas%5C%5Ddf%28%29%28%5D%29%28asd%28asdf%29%29%29%29%28asdf%29%5C%28asdf%28%3F%3Dasdf%29%5C%5Basdf%28%5Cads%5C%5D%5C%28%29%28%29).